# SparkML MultilayerPerceptron error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have the following model that I would like to estimate using  SparkML `MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()`.

```
val formula = new RFormula()
  .setFormula("vtplus15predict~ vhisttplus15 + vhistt + vt + vtminus15 + Time + Length + Day")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setLabelCol("label")

formula.fit(data).transform(data)
```

**Note:** The features is a vector and label is a Double

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = false)
```

I define my MLP estimator as follows:

```
val layers = Array[Int](6, 5, 8, 1) //I suspect this is where it went wrong

val mlp = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()
  .setLayers(layers)
  .setBlockSize(128)
  .setSeed(1234L)
  .setMaxIter(100)

// train the model
val model = mlp.fit(train)
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LabelConverter$.encodeLabeledPoint(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier$$anonfun$3.apply(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:245)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier$$anonfun$3.apply(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:245)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:363)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:935)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:950)
>       ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to first find the local optimal that allows one to escape the ArrayIndexOutBound and then use brute-force search to find the global optimal.  Shaido suggest  finding `n`

> For example, val layers =
>   Array[Int](6, 5, 8, n). This assumes the length of the feature vectors
>   are 6. – Shaido

So make `n` be a large integer(`n =100`) then manually use brute-force search to arrive at a good solution(`n =50`  then try `n =32` - error, `n = 35`  - perfect).

Credit to Shaido.

Answer (score 5):

> org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LabelConverter$.encodeLabeledPoint(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:121)

This tells us that an array is out of bounds in the `MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala` file, let's look at the code there:

```
def encodeLabeledPoint(labeledPoint: LabeledPoint, labelCount: Int): (Vector, Vector) = {
  val output = Array.fill(labelCount)(0.0)
  output(labeledPoint.label.toInt) = 1.0
  (labeledPoint.features, Vectors.dense(output))
}
```

It performs a one-hot encoding of the labels in the dataset. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs since the `output` array is too short.

By going back in the code, it's possible to find that `labelCount` is the same as the number of output nodes in the `layers` array. In other words, the number of output nodes should be the same as the number of classes. Looking at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier) for MLP there is the following line:

> The number of nodes N in the output layer corresponds to the number of classes.

**The solution is therefore to either:**

1. Change the number of nodes in the final layer of the network (output nodes)
2. Reconstruct the data to have the same number of classes as your network output nodes.

**Note**: The final output layer should always be 2 or more, never 1, since there should be one node per class and a problem with a single class does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

rearrange your dataset as the error shows you have fewer arrays than you have in your features set or your data set has a null set which prompted an error.I came across this type of error while working on my MLP project.hope my answer helps you.
thanks for reaching out